# Generate a Rectangular Pulse in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I need to create a rectangular pulse with `width = 7` and a range `(-T/2, T/2)` where `T` 59 msec.

I wrote this code but I'm not sure if that's correct.

```matlab
w = 7;
T = 59;
t = -T/2:1:T/2;

rect = rectpuls(t, w);
plot(t, rect);
```

This code generates a rectangular pulse but I'm not sure if it's right. Also, I'm not quite sure what the `t = -T/2:1:T/2;` means. I mean the range is from -29.5 to 29.5 with step **1**. When I set this to **0.1** or **0.01** my pulse is better. Why does this affect my output?

Note that the second thing I have to do is to create a periodic sequence of clock pulses. I don't know if this affects the way I must implement my initial rectangular pulse.

Comment: What do you mean when you say “my pulse is better”? When more finely sampled, you should have more samples in the pulse, but the signal still should have zero values outside the pulse, and whatever constant positive values inside.

Comment: I mean more rectangular if that makes sense . I'm new to all of these so you have to excuse me.

Comment: Well, your signal is defined only on the sample points, the plot has straight lines in between. The closer the points are together, the more vertical that straight line will be from one sample with a value of 0 to the next sample with a value of 1. But that is just the plot, the signal is still equally sharp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you increase the number of increments a numerical function (such as Matlab `rectpuls`) uses in its process of discretizing the continuous, you'll have as consequence that the accuracy of said function is going to improve, at the expense (in this case, negligible) of added computational cost. You are doing exactly this, when you discretize employing smaller time-steps, from `1` to `0.1` to `0.01`.

To create a periodic sequence of identical rectangular pulses, you can call the function in a loop:

```
w = 7;
T = 59;
t = -T/2:1:T/2;
t_size = size(t);
N = 10;
rect = zeros(N, t_size(2));
interval = 20;

figure
plot(t, rectpuls(t, w));
xlim([-20 (N + 1)*interval]);
ylim([0 1.1]);
hold on
for i = 1:N
    t = (-T/2 + i*interval): 1 :(T/2 + i*interval);
    rect(i,:) = rectpuls(t - i * interval, w);
    plot(t, rect(i,:));
    hold on
end
```

The above should generate identical rectangular pulses every `interval = 20 ms`, over a time length of `interval * (N + 1) = 220 ms`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have edited out the error, this may work but I cannot check the code in Matlab right now.

Comment: Hey nice, thanks a lot! We could say that is like sampling? We are more accurate that's why the pulse is more rectangular?

Comment: @Andrew you can refer to this picture: https://www.cradle-cfd.com/dcms_media/image/en_column_basic_fig5.1.jpg  
The smaller the step, the thinner the blue histogram bars that approximate the continuous function (red, dots) will be... Which means that yes, more points in the red functions will be sampled, leading to better accuracy. To the limit of `step = 0`, in which case the blue histogram would be continuous, and would perfectly approximate the red function.

Comment: Thank you so much. One more thing, the N in the code that you wrote means how many pulses we will get in a periodic sequence. For instance if ```N = 100``` then will get 100 rectangular pulses? And the ```size(t)``` has to do with the width?

Comment: @Andrew Yes `N` is the number of pulses, each distant `200 ms` from the next. `size(t)` does not have to do with the width (you can control the width with `w`), but is the number of sampled points for each pulse, and is needed by the `plot` function.